# Attempt to de-reference a null object: Salesforce

Tags: apex-code

I am trying to submit data to a server where it is picked and stored in salesforce. The error I am getting is "Attempt to de-reference a null object" at the server. so I am wondering what the problem is...
Below is the sample code:

```
public static List<String> processAgentVisitSurvey(ProcessSurveySubmission.SurveySubmission submission, Map<String, Submission_Answer__c> answers, Person__c person) {

    // Load the TDR
    TDR__c tdr = loadTdr(person);

    if (tdr == null) {

        //Send an email saying that an unregistered person is trying to act a TDR

        // Send back the error message
        return new String[] { '0', 'User with handset Id ' + submission.imei + ' is not a TDR', 'SUPRESSMSG' };
    }
```

This is the source of the error message.

There is a class the redirects to this method:

```
private static List<String> additionalProcessing(
        SurveySubmission surveySubmission,
        Survey__c survey,
        Person__c interviewer,
        Id intervieweeId
) {
    List<String> returnValues = new List<String>();

    Map<String, Submission_Answer__c> answers = parseSubmissionToMap(surveySubmission);

    // Find the name of the method that this survey hooks into to do its post processing
    try {
        if (survey.Post_Processing_Method__c.equalsIgnoreCase('None')) {
            returnValues.add('0');
            returnValues.add('There is no post processing method specified for this survey');
            returnValues.add('SUPRESSMSG');
        }
        else if (survey.Post_Processing_Method__c.equals('CKW_Registration')) {
            return CkwRegistration.processCkwRegistration(answers, interviewer);
        }
        else if (survey.Post_Processing_Method__c.equals('CKW_Baseline')) {
            return CkwRegistration.processCkwBaseline(answers, interviewer);
        }
        else if (survey.Post_Processing_Method__c.equals('CKW_Staff_Update')) {
            return CkwRegistration.processCkwUpdate(answers, interviewer);
        }
        else if (survey.Post_Processing_Method__c.equals('Subcounty_Registration')) {
            return CkwRegistration.processSubcounties(answers, interviewer);
        }
        else if (survey.Post_Processing_Method__c.equals('TDR_AGENT_VISIT')) {
            return TdrHelpers.processAgentVisitSurvey(surveySubmission, answers, interviewer);
        }
        else if (survey.Post_Processing_Method__c.equals('UDOM_RAIN_GUAGE')) {
            return UDoMSurveyProcessing.processDailyRainGauge(surveySubmission, answers, interviewer);
        }
        else if (survey.Post_Processing_Method__c.equals('UDOM_RAIN_GUAGE_REG')) {
            return UDoMSurveyProcessing.registerRainGauge(surveySubmission, answers, interviewer);
        }
        else if (survey.Post_Processing_Method__c.equals('MTN_CHANNELS')) {
            return MtnChannelsHelpers.processChannelsFFPSSurvey(surveySubmission, answers, interviewer);
        }
        else if (survey.Post_Processing_Method__c.equals('FHI_GROUP_REGISTRATION')) {
        return FHISurveysHelpers.processGroupRegistration(surveySubmission, answers, interviewer, survey.Survey_Name__c);
        }
        else if (survey.Post_Processing_Method__c.equals('FHI_HOUSEHOLD_REGISTRATION')) {
           return FHISurveysHelpers.processHouseholdRegistration(surveySubmission, answers, interviewer, survey.Survey_Name__c);
        }
//           else if (survey.Post_Processing_Method__c.equals('Colombia_Farmer_Registration')) {
//               return ColombiaFarmerRegistrationPostProcessor.processSubmission(surveySubmission, answers, interviewer);
//           }
        else if (survey.Post_Processing_Method__c.equals('FIELD_OFFICER_SUPPORT')) {
            return FieldOfficeHelpers.processFoSurvey(surveySubmission, answers, interviewer);
        }
//           else if (survey.Post_Processing_Method__c.equals('DATA_VALIDATOR_SPOT_CHECK')) {
//               return DataValidatorHelpers.processSpotCheck(surveySubmission, answers, interviewer);
//          }
//            else if (survey.Post_Processing_Method__c.equals('DATA_VALIDATOR_BACK_CHECK')) {
//                return DataValidatorHelpers.processBackCheck(surveySubmission, answers, interviewer);
//            }
        else if (survey.Post_Processing_Method__c.equals('EQUIPMENT_TRACKING')) {
            return EquipmentTrackingHelpers.processFieldOfficerSubmission(surveySubmission, answers, interviewer);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        returnValues.add('0');
        returnValues.add(e.getMessage());
        returnValues.add('An error occured. Please contact support');
    }
    return returnValues;
}
```

which I think is fine...

Please help coz I do not seem to see any problem
Thank you. I hope the code provide is enough.

Comment: Please, write a line where the error occurs.

For now it's just you use not initialized variable. What is this variable and why... It's hard to tell you without knowing where the error occurs.

Comment: you'll run into a lot of null reference errors if you just say SomeObject.SomeField__c.someStringMethod();.  This is because they do not always have values and will be null.  I wrote a wrapper method called 'getSObjectField()' and i put it in a service class.  Essentially it does this:  `(someField == null) ? '' : someField;`  This returns an empty string if the value is null, otherwise it returns the value.  THis is helpful to avoid those null errors when directly referencing sobject fields!

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I run across that error my first instinct is to look for any queries.  In APEX when you return a null value (expected or not) into a single item such as `Person__c person = [query that returns objects};` that error is thrown.

The SOLUTION is to ensure data gets returned into a concrete SObject such as...

`List<Person__c> persons = [Here is a query or method call];`

Then you would check the list with `persons.size()`  This obeys salesforce's Bulkify everything approach they enforce as well as a more robust backend.

Sorry I couldn't provide more support, the error wasn't very evident in your code samples without a line number or debug log.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Be aware: This error can also appear if you are trying to reference an uninstantiated property of a class.

Example: If you declare a List property of a class, but never instantiate it, and then attempt to add to that list, you will get this error.